# Why I can't add TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All when I have AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount App

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm facing a problem where I can't add the TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All permission to my app registered in Azure AD which also supports Personal Microsoft Accounts. Despite having the necessary admin consent for other similar permissions, this specific permission doesn't seem to be available or is not getting added. I need this permission to manage team settings in Microsoft Teams. Could someone explain why this is happening and how to resolve it?

[image]

It's working for `AzureADMultipleOrgs` but not for `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount`

Answer (score 0):

`TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All` permission is not supported for personal Microsoft accounts, as indicated in the documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

This means that if your application is registered to support both Azure AD accounts (work or school accounts) and personal Microsoft accounts, you won't be able to add the `TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All` permission.
To resolve this issue, you would need to register your application to only support accounts in any organizational directory (Azure AD accounts). This is also known as `AzureADMultipleOrgs` and it supports the `TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All` permission.